# Glut/OpenGL: how to bind array of coordinates to mesh object to traslate/rotate them

Tags: c, opengl, glut, mesh

In my GLUT/OpenGL execercise I have to load 3 different objects whose I was give a file.m. This is done by reading that file, creating a list and finally calling glCallList(). How I have to enable the possibility of translating and rotating the objects, after selecting one. So I have:

```
#define OBJECTS 3
float objAngle[OBJECTS], objAxis[OBJECTS][3], objWAxis[OBJECTS][3], objPos[OBJECTS][3], objWPos[OBJECTS][3];
float objScale[OBJECTS] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
float translation_var[OBJECTS][3];
translation_var[i][0] = translation_var[i][1] = translation_var[i][2] = 0.0;
```

and they are all initialized with 0.0

Moreover I have:

```
float ocsmatrix[OBJECTS][16];
float wcsmatrix[OBJECTS][16];
```

initialized to:

```
for(i = 0; i < OBJECTS; i++) {
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ocsmatrix[i]);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, wcsmatrix[i]);
}
```

And this is a part of my keyboard function:

```
void keyboard (unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
float* pos = NULL;
float step = 0.0;

if( mode == MODE_CHANGE_EYE_POS ) {
}

else if( mode == MODE_CHANGE_REFERENCE_POS ) {
    pos = camC;
    step = 0.1;
}

else if( mode == MODE_CHANGE_UP_POS ) {
    pos = camU;
    step = 0.1;
}

else if( mode == MODE_CHANGE_LIGHT_POS ) {
    pos = lightPos;
    step = 1.0;
}

else if( mode == MODE_ROTATE_OBJECT ) {
}


if( pos != NULL ) {
    if( key == 'x' )
        pos[0] += step;
    else if( key == 'X' )
        pos[0] -= step;
    else if( key == 'y' )
        pos[1] += step;
    else if( key == 'Y' )
        pos[1] -= step;
    else if( key == 'z' )
        pos[2] += step;
    else if( key == 'Z' )
        pos[2] -= step;

}

if (key == 'l') {
    char path[32];
    printf("Digitare file.m da caricare: data/file.m\n");
    scanf("%s", path);

    loadMeshModel(path); /* carico il file.m digitato da console */
}

if (key == '0') {
    selected_object = 1;
    printf("SELEZIONATO OGGETTO 0\n");
}
if (key == '1') {
    selected_object = 2;
    printf("SELEZIONATO OGGETTO 1\n");
}
if (key == '2') {
    selected_object = 3;
    printf("SELEZIONATO OGGETTO 2\n");
}

// gestione trasformazioni OCS
if(key == 'o') {
    mode = MODE_TRANSLATE_OCS;
    printf("TRASLAZIONE OCS ATTIVA\n");
}
else if(key == 'O') {
    mode = MODE_ROTATE_OCS;
    printf("ROTAZIONE OCS ATTIVA\n");
}

// gestione trasformazioni WCS
if(key == 'w') {
    mode = MODE_TRANSLATE_WCS;
    printf("TRASLAZIONE WCS ATTIVA\n");
}
else if(key == 'W') {
    mode = MODE_ROTATE_WCS;
    printf("ROTAZIONE WCS ATTIVA\n");
}

if(key == 'q') {
    mode = MODE_QUADRICS;
}
else if(key == 'Q') {
    mode = MODE_MODELS;
}

if( key ==  27 ) //esc
    exit(1);

if(selected_object > -1) {
    if(mode == MODE_TRANSLATE_OCS) {
        step = 0.1;
    }

    else if(mode == MODE_TRANSLATE_WCS) {
        step = 0.1;
    }

    else if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glMultMatrixf(ocsmatrix[selected_object]);
        step = 2.0;

    } else if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS) {
        glPushMatrix();
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glMultMatrixf(wcsmatrix[selected_object]);
        step = 2.0;
    }
}

if( selected_object > -1 )
{
    if( key == 'x' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][0] += step;

        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS)
            glRotatef(-step, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    else if( key == 'X' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][0] -= step;
        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS)
            glRotatef(step, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    else if( key == 'y' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][1] += step;
        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS)
            glRotatef(-step, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    else if( key == 'Y' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][1] -= step;
        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS)
            glRotatef(step, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    }

    else if( key == 'z' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][2] += step;
        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS)
            glRotatef(-step, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }

    else if( key == 'Z' ) {
        translation_var[selected_object][2] -= step;
        if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS || mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS) 
            glRotatef(step, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
}

// Save rotation in relative matrixes
if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_OCS) {
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ocsmatrix[selected_object]);
    glPopMatrix();
}
else if(mode == MODE_ROTATE_WCS) {
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, wcsmatrix[selected_object]);
    glPopMatrix();
}

glutPostRedisplay();

}
```

and finally this is display()

```
  glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

glShadeModel (GL_SMOOTH);  //GL_FLAT

glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos );
glEnable( GL_LIGHTING );
glEnable( GL_LIGHT0 );
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);

glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity ();
gluPerspective( fovy, aspect, 1, 100);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt( camE[0], camE[1], camE[2], camC[0], camC[1], camC[2], camU[0], camU[1], camU[2] );

// Trackball rotation.
glRotatef(tbAngle, tbAxis[0], tbAxis[1], tbAxis[2]);

glLineWidth(2);
drawAxis( 2.0, 1 );
glLineWidth(1);

glRotatef(angle[0], 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle[1], 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(angle[2], 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

//draw the mesh model
drawAxis( 1.0, 0 );

for(i=0; i<loaded_objects; i++) {
    glPushMatrix();

        glMultMatrixf(wcsmatrix[i]);
        glTranslatef(objWPos[i][0] + translation_var[i][0], objWPos[i][1] + translation_var[i][1], objWPos[i][2] + translation_var[i][2]);


        glMultMatrixf(ocsmatrix[i]);
        glTranslatef(objPos[i][0]+translation_var[i][0], objPos[i][1]+translation_var[i][1], objPos[i][2]+translation_var[i][2]);


        glScalef( objScale[i], objScale[i], objScale[i]);

        //draw the model
        if(!wireframe)
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
        else
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

        glCallList(listname+i);

    glPopMatrix();

}

glutSwapBuffers();
```

So, these are the button I press in my keyboard after the mesg object (in my case a "pig") is showed at the centre of the 3 axes:

- "1" --> I select the pig (selected_object = 1)
- "o" --> I enable ocs translation
- "x" or "X" to move the pig along the X ax

But the pug doesn't move. Why? It seems to work only with translate_var[3] and not with translate_var[3][3]. But if I use a mono-dimension array then I would translate all the 3 mesh objects...
Moreover, how the bind between the i-mesh object and the i-th position in objPos/objWPos is done?

Comment: I'm sorry...this course of CG has been a disaster since it began. Not only for the deprecated functions but also because we saw really too much math... And few things strictly linked to programming...anyway, if you can answer my question with some hints I would appreciate it

Comment: There's no such thing as "too much math" in computer graphics.

Answer (score 1):

Your main mistake/misconception is, that you think of OpenGL as if it were some kind of 3D scene manager. It is not. All OpenGL does is drawing points, lines or triangles, one at a time. Display Lists are kind of macro recordings, nothing more.

In your keyboard handler function you react to the events by manipulating the OpenGL transformation matrices. However these matrices are just another input into the drawing process. Just manipulating them has no effect whatsoever. Furthermore there's no "association" between matrices and "models" because, well, OpenGL doesn't have models.

So what you have to do is, in your keyboard handler use the input to manipulate variables that you define; one set of variables for each object (hint: `struct`), then flag GLUT that it shall call the display handler upon the next iteration of the main application loop (`glutPostRedisplay`). Then in the display routine use the values of the variables you manipulated in the input event handler to set up the corresponding transformation matrices of each model you want to draw *right before you draw* that model.